# Encode string as hex bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string '123456ffffffff'. How do I get the following

```
[0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff]
```

The input string will only contain digits. The output could be a bytearray or simply an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not concerned about 3.x compatibility, then:

```
s = '123456ffffffff'
result = list(bytearray(s.decode('hex')))
# [18, 52, 86, 255, 255, 255, 255]
```

For 3.x, and for compatibility, it's better to use `unhexlify`:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
result = list(bytearray(unhexlify(s)))
```

So, if you don't need a `bytearray` for anything, you can end up with:

```
result = [ord(ch) for ch in unhexlify(s)]
```